# Exponential sums for beginner.

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, textbook-recommendation, analytic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis

What are the good books, online lecture notes or starting material on exponentials sums with applications in number theory for a beginner, apart from N. M. Korobov's book? The book or notes should cover methods of Weyl, van der Corput and Vinogradov, with some details.

Comment: First, I think this should be CW since it's asking for a list of good books. Second, if you're no longer a beginner, having read the below references, then I recommend Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic* for some of the higher level applications of exponential sums. Third, there seem to be some nice references for beginners at this link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeylSum.html

Comment: I retagged history-overview since the methods the OP seems particularly interested in the historical development (based on which methods he's asking for).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shparlinski has a nice set of lecture notes, aimed at beginners, with a view towards applications: http://www2.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/coding/files/ishpar.ps

Answer (score 6):

For van der Corput's method and some developpments, including the Bombieri-Iwaniec method, the book of Graham and Kolesnik "Van der Corput's method of exponential sums" is one of the best sources.

Comment: This is really nice little book, thanks :).

Answer (score 5):

Ten Lectures on the interface of harmonic analysis and  number theory by Hugh Montgomery covers these things (Chapters 2 and 3).

Answer (score 3):

K. Chandrasekharan, Exponential sums in the development of number theory, pp. 7-26 in 
Proceedings of the International Conference on Number Theory (Moscow, 1971), Trudy Mat. Inst. Steklov 132 (1973).

Comment: I was able to see this in its entirety on google books here:http://books.google.com/books?id=pYfXq6XjjCcC&lpg=PA3&ots=ZnOO4XMO7D&dq=chandrasekharan%20exponential%20sums&lr&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=chandrasekharan%20exponential%20sums&f=false ! Also, the pages ran from 3 to 24...

Comment: Ah, 3-24 is the page range in the AMS republication of that volume (1975).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you will find something useful in the book of Iwaniec & Kowalski entitled " Analytic Number Theory". Morever, I think Huxley's "Area, Lattice Points and Exponential Sums" is worthwhile to read, which focuses a new method deveploed by Bombieri, Iwaniec, Huxley himself and many other followers.